# Referencing Variable for Functions

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Every two weeks there will be a new table with new data coming in to me, I need to update that onto a master table. I want to automate this process.

I would like to declare a variable that a user can input the date the data is from, and based on that date update to the appropriate field on the master table. I have no clue how to make SQL functions use variables to locate tables with the syntax, not even sure if this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

**As I am inexperienced, I am making a VBA Macro and embedding the SQL code from the access query I made.**

```vba
Sub UpdateFieldX()

    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE [15-Jun-16] " & _
    "RIGHT JOIN MasterSPI " & _
    "ON [15-Jun-16].[SR#] = MasterSPI.[SR#] " & _
    "SET MasterSPI.[30-Jun-16] = [15-Jun-16].[SPI]; " _

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Comment: This would require stored procedure not a function and would then require dynamic SQL inside of the stored procedure.  It might be better to build the dynamic sql pointing to the correct table in your macro and then execute it there.  Please be sure are validating user input so you are not susceptible to a sql injection attack.

Comment: Yes, So I have two tables, and they will both have an identical field called SR number. I only want to update values on the master table where there are matching records according to that identical SR number field.  The rest with unmatched SR will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this and used an Update Query and Insert Query.
It sounds like you're trying to just update any existing records that may need updating and then adding new records into the table.

For an update, I'd try creating a query in SQL view and type something like:

`UPDATE MasterSPI SET MasterSPI.SRnumber = [newtablename]![SRnumber]` etc.

and do that for each field in your table.

For inserting you could do something like:

`INSERT INTO MasterSPI SELECT * FROM newtablename`

That may help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I know many of you are advanced users but I found an answer that fit my quick needs. As a notice and disclaimer for other people, it will be in no way secure, it is more for personal use such that I do not need to spend an hour doing append and updates to several master tables repetitively.

To do this, I made a global string variable called name, then I made another variable called strung that translated it into a readable string for referencing. I then made an SQL string that references that strung variable. This allows the user to submit an input for the global variable, which translates into a readable string for the RunSQL method.

Here's a snippet of the parts that were most relevant, I hope it helps whoever comes next with the same scenario.

```
** 
Public name As String 'global variable declared so that the new field to be created can be used elsewhere

name = InputBox("Name of Month", "InputBox") 'variable that takes user input and it will be name for new fields to be added

Dim SQLa As String 'creates a string variable such that it will be read as an SQL line by the RunSQL method

strung = "[" & name & "]" 'sets strung as global varible name, which is user input on the specific table being used to update

'the following lines runs a query such that it updates the master table with new data and does the grouping by SR number

SQLa = "UPDATE " & strung & " " & _
"RIGHT JOIN MasterSPI " & _
"ON " & strung & "." & "[SR#] = MasterSPI.[SR#] " & _
"SET MasterSPI." & strung & " = " & strung & "." & "[SPI]; " _
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLa 'executes the SQL code in VBA **
```